# ReferenceError using Session.getActiveUser() in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script and am trying to use Session.getActiveUser() but get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined" error in the Developer Tools view.  This is a Published Web App running as the User.  It is happening when testing with the latest code.  It is in a Google Apps for Education domain.

This may or may not be related:  I had also tried to use Utilities.sleep() which gave me the same error for Utilities.  I worked around this issue.

Is there an Advanced Google Service I need to turn on or some other setting I need to make?  My ultimate goal is to be able to add the name of the person running the script to a cell in the spreadsheet.  Once I can retrieve their name I have the rest.

Regards,
Karl

Comment: do show a minimal sample that reproduces the issue. are you sure your function is not in the htmlService client side?

Comment: Actually I am sure it IS in the HTMLservice Client Side.  It has to be server side?  I will test that later.

Comment: 100% of all appscript apis need to get called server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling the appscript api from the HtmlService clientside javascript. no apps script apis can get called client-side, must be in your .gs or in templated html.

To call a server function from the client side, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: Confirmed that was the problem.  Thank you!